# Any way to programmatically detect the HTTP status code for the IEs res://ieframe.dll/* errors?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, iframe, access-denied

Thinking of a way to differentiate between `res://ieframe.dll/*` errors, a logical thought was, why not to check `src` attribute of the iframe and parse it for the actual error. But it seems that `src` of the iframe (as well as the url in main window) doesn't change to `res://ieframe.dll/*`? If that's the case then where does "Access Denied" (cross-origin error) come from when I try to access the content of the iframe?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what was HTTP response that caused the "Access Denied" error in iframe. If it is possible at all? 404 or 503, etc.

Comment: Use the network request viewer in F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: I mean programmatically, through js that is.